# Sería alguien tan amable de resolverme mi duda

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

He terminado una aplicación en Java Netbeans, funciona muy bien y todo dentro del entorno. Lo que me intriga mucho es como puedo yo adjuntar mi base de datos al jar para que a la hora de abrir la aplicación en otro dispositivo este me funcione si pedirme excepciónes de la bd.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. Tómate un momento y lee lo que has escrito. Pides ayuda y no dejas código ni nada. Lee [ask] si aún no lo has hecho y edita tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1):

1. Si es una base embedida como sqlite o h2: Por ingenieria, deberias craer la funcionalidad (osea una clase, un script etc) dentro de la aplicacion, que cree la base de datos (ya que es algo critico para el sistema). No simplemente validar la conexion apenas inicia la Aplicación.
2. Si no es embebida,como sql, mysql, etc. Tendrias que crear una funcionalidad donde se configure la conexion al servicio, y que cree las bases y estructuras necesarias.

Comment: Trabaje la bd desde Phpmyadmin

Comment: Bueno, Phpmyadmin es simplemente un gestor, como HeidiSQL (osea son programas para gestionar con la base de datos, no la base de datos en sí, son meras interfaces). Asumo que estás con MYSQL. En ese caso, tu programa debería contar con una interfaz inicial, donde se puedan configurar los parámetros para una conexión a dicho servicio (mysql), y en caso de que no existan las bases y tablas necesarias, el programa debería crearlas (ya que es critico para el funcionamiento). El dispositivo que vaya a utilizar tu programa, por supuesto, debe tener instalado MYSQL.

Comment: Deberias revisar la ingenieria del sistema en si, y evaluar si no seria mejor migrarse a una base de datos local embebida como sqlite (https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) o h2 (https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). Ya que no requieren configuracion previa, ni instalaciones previas, etc. Por otro lado si por requerimiento tienen que usar MYSQL,  van a tener que asegurarse de que el dispositivo done se va a ejecutar el programa, cuente con los requerimientos para funcionar (mysql version xx.xx.xx), etc.

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo de como sería el codigo, para que en caso de que no exista las bases y tablas este la cree 

Comment: La verdad que no tengo instalado ningun ide para trabajar con java, ni tampoco el JDK. Pero es mas facil de lo que pensas. Seria simpemente tener las querys de los "create" de cada tabla y base, y ejecutarlos como cualquier otra consulta a mysql.

Answer (score -1):

siempre tienes que instalar MYSQL en la maquina cliente donde vas a instalar tu programa a parte de que tienes que exportar la base de datos con la misma configuracion y usuarios que utilizaste en la maquina donde hiciste tu apliacion.